# React native Textinput alignment ios

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm developing an app where there are textInputs and the text could be English or Arabic, on android the text alignment is based on the keyboard language, if English it's LTR and if it's Arabic it's RTL.
But in IOS It's based on the device language and the alignment dose not change.

I'm using react native 0.62.2.

Note, i started developing the app on expo and the problem wasn't there but after ejecting the project it started.